# Python Tkinter Entry Фильтрация текста при вставке

Tags: python, tkinter, entry

**Стоит задача: Допустить ко вводу в Entry только цифры.**

Есть код, который обрабатывает ввод с клавиатуры.
Если вставить в Entry "123123" - все ок.
Если - "1231232h","1231232   ", "    1231232h" - в Entry останется прежний текст.

Какой метод применить, чтобы при вставке такого рода строк оставались только цифры?
Пример: хочу вставить "    1231232h" - вставляется "1231232"

**Строка должна быть определенной длинны, н-р 8 символьная.**

P.S.
Код который обрабатывает ввод с клавиатуры:

```
def is_valid(newval):
    return re.match("^\d{0,8}$", newval) is not None


root = Tk()
    root.title("Hi, boss")
    root.geometry("240x80")
    check = (root.register(is_valid), "%P")
    entr = ttk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=check,justify='center')
    entr.pack()
```

Comment: Здесь код не полный. Где объявлена переменная `re`?

Comment: @Master'sTime, `re` - это модуль из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: re - модуль регулярных выражений

Comment: Для начала https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter/4140988#4140988

Comment: @СергейКох позвольте пример с участием данного метода касательно моего примера

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```py
import tkinter as tk
def check(*_):
    if not entry.var.get().isdigit():
        new = ""
        for i in entry.var.get():
            if i.isdigit():
                new+=i
        entry.var.set(new)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.var = tk.StringVar()
    entry['textvariable'] = entry.var
    entry.var.trace_add('write', check)
    entry.pack()

    tk.mainloop()
```

P.S. Это ответ на первый вопрос(до того, как поменяли вопрос)

Comment: К сожалению, ваше решение у меня не работает...

Comment: у вас какая версия python?

Comment: Python 3.8.6

Я имею ввиду, что конечную задачу это не решает. Есть решение связанное с уже существующим кодом?